# Como puedo iterar el siguiente diccionario de datos en Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

tengo los siguientes módelos en python:

```
class ModuleType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    icon = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    state = models.IntegerField(choices=state_choices, default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.name)

class Module(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name='Url',unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name='Nombre',unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True,blank=True,verbose_name='Descripción')
    icon = models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name='Icono',null=True,blank=True,unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='modulo/%Y/%m/%d',verbose_name='Imagen',null=True,blank=True)
    type = models.ForeignKey(ModuleType,null=True,blank=True)
    dropdown = models.BooleanField(default=True,verbose_name='Despegable')
    state = models.IntegerField(choices=state_choices, default=1,verbose_name='Estado')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.name)
```

Tengo la siguiente función en python:

```
def generate_treeview(id):
    data = {}
    modules = Module.objects.filter(groupmodule__groups_id=2, state=1, dropdown=True).exclude(type=None)
    for t in ModuleType.objects.filter(state=1,module__in=list(modules.values_list(flat=True))):
        data[t] = modules.filter(type=t)
    return data
```

Me da como resultado si lo imprimo lo siguiente:

```
{<ModuleType: Seguridad>: <QuerySet [<Module: Tipos de Módulos>, <Module: Módulos>, <Module: Grupos>]>, <ModuleType: Publicidad>: <QuerySet [<Module: Portadas>]>}
```

Como hago para iterarlo en un template.?? Lo hice de la siguiente manera pero me funciona.

```
        {% for t in rmoduletreev %}
            <li class="treeview">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="{{ t.icon }}" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="text-right-treeview">{{ t.name }}</span>
                    <span class="pull-right-container">
                  <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                </span>
                </a>
                <ul class="treeview-menu">
                     {% for mod in t.objects.all %}
                         <li><a href="{{ mod.url }}"><i class="{{ mod.icon }}"></i> {{ mod.name }}</a></li>
                       <p>{{ value }}</p>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La primera observación que te hago es sobre esta línea:

```
for t in ModuleType.objects.filter(state=1, module__in=list(modules.values_list(flat=True))):
```

En el `module__in` si pasas como argumento `list()` que contiene un queryset, entonces estas obligando a Django a ejecutar el query, por lo que tienes una consulta de más, en realidad, tiene el mismo resultado, sólo que mas optimo si dejas esa línea así:

```
for t in ModuleType.objects.filter(state=1, module__in=modules.values_list(flat=True)):
```

Asumiendo que en tu template, la variable `rmoduletreev` es el resultado de la función `generate_treeview` entonces tienes que tener en cuenta que tu estructura de datos es la siguiente:

```
data = {
    Objeto<ModuleType>: Array<Objeto<Module>>
}
```

Por lo que `t` (en tu template) viene siendo un objeto instancia de `ModuleType`, entonces, ¿Dónde está el error?

Cuando quieres recorrer el Queryset recuerda que tienes un queryset ya, y ese queryset no tiene el atributo `objects`, algo ocurre con las variables en los templates de Django, y es que si fallan, entonces no arrojará error, siempre y cuando el error esté dentro de la plantilla, y obviamente al `t` ser una instancia, no puede acceder a su propiedad `objects` tampoco.

Para solucionar el error, debes pensar cómo python recorre diccionarios en un for loop, y lo hace de la forma:

```
for x, y in diccionary:
   # donde x es el key
   # donde y es el value
```

Esa misma forma puedes usar en tu template, quedando de esta forma:

```
{% for t, ti in rmoduletreev %}
     <li class="treeview">
         <a href="#">
             <i class="{{ t.icon }}" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="text-right-treeview">{{ t.name }}</span>
                <span class="pull-right-container">
              <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
            </span>
            </a>
            <ul class="treeview-menu">
                 {% for mod in ti %}
                     <li><a href="{{ mod.url }}"><i class="{{ mod.icon }}"></i> {{ mod.name }}</a></li>
                   <p>{{ value }}</p>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comentame si eso ayuda a solucionar tu problema

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió mucho.. Saludos +10

Answer (score 0):

te deberia de valer con hacer lo siguiente en la plantilla

```
    {% for t in rmoduletreev.moduletype %}
        .....
        .....
    {% endfor %}
```